# How do I connect to a local SQL Server in a WPF form?

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using this in a WPF C# form:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local)\MSSQLSERVER; Initial Catalog=CODEXLoginDB; Integrated Security=True;");
```

to connect to the SQL server running on my computer, but I'm getting an error:

> "SQL Network Interfaces error:25"

whenever I run the program. I'm trying to connect to a database within the server called `CODEXLoginDB` to check if a value entered in the program is the same as the one in a table in the database.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Change (local)\MSSQLSERVER with just the name of your computer. Did you try to connect using Sql Server Managerment Studio? Just copy the login information from there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336613/sql-network-interfaces-error-25-connection-string-is-not-valid-in-powershell).  It speaks of _PowerShell_ but the cause and fix are perhaps the same

Comment: Typically if you create the default instance of SQL server then just "localhost" as the Data Source should work.